TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable - I can't seem to solve it
I am trying to create a local chatbot using LM Studio. I have the latest openai python library installed. However, when I run my 'app.py' file it states that
line 25, in 
response = chat_with_gpt(human_input)
line 17, in chat_with_gpt
return completion.choices[0].message.content.strip()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
I can't see where I am going wrong. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
The full code is below:
import openai

openai.api_type = "open_ai"
openai.base_url = "http://127.0.0.1:1234"
openai.api_key = "NULL"



def chat_with_gpt(prompt):
    completion = openai.chat.completions.create(
        messages = [
            {"role": "user",
             "content": prompt}
        ],
        model="llama3"
    )
    return completion.choices[0].message.content.strip()

while True:
    human_input = input("Human: ")
    
    if human_input.lower() in ["quit", "exit", "bye"]:
        break
    
    response = chat_with_gpt(human_input)
    
    print("Chatbot: ", response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        human_input = input("Human: ")

        if human_input.lower() in ["quit", "exit", "bye"]:
            break

        response = chat_with_gpt(human_input)

        print("Chatbot: ", response)

I have reviewed the api guide from openAI but I can't solve the TypeError. If you haven't guessed I am a noob at this.

That means that completion.choices is None. Check the docs to see what that indicates. Maybe that there were no completion suggestions?

I assume you have an actual API key in your code and not "NULL"?

Because I am running the model locally, I don't need the api key. I leave it in there for an instance where I would connect to openAI.

The error message shows that completion.choices[0].message is None. You didn't get a valid answer from openai.You must have a valid API key and go to the OpenAI API webpage to learn how to use this API.This is an example taken from that webpage.
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4o",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Write a haiku about recursion in programming."
        }
    ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message)

With this little code you can see what is wrong in your code.

Thanks for your assistance here. I have managed to tidy up my code. Below is the code that worked for me.
from openai import OpenAI

# Point to the local server
client = OpenAI(base_url="http://localhost:1234/v1", api_key="lm-studio")

def chat_with_gpt(prompt):

    completion = client.chat.completions.create(
        messages = [
            {"role": "user",
             "content": prompt}
        ],
        model="llama-3.2-3b-instruct",
        temperature=0.8
    )
    return completion.choices[0].message.content.strip()

while True:
    human_input = input("Human: ")

    if human_input.lower() in ["quit", "exit", "bye"]:
        break

    response = chat_with_gpt(human_input)

    print("Chatbot: ", response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        human_input = input("Human: ")

        if human_input.lower() in ["quit", "exit", "bye"]:
            break

        response = chat_with_gpt(human_input)

        print("Chatbot: ", response)

